# Regarding difference in execution time of queries

Tags: oracle, performance

These are two explain plans of two different queries that return the same results but at a drastically different speed (280 second vs 1-7 seconds).
I want some help knowing what the fast query has so that I can replicate it in the future.

EDIT:

Here is the explain plan for the fast query:

```
Plan hash value: 3147806849

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                                          | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                   |                               |     1 |   528 |    46   (9)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |   1 |  NESTED LOOPS SEMI                                 |                               |     1 |   528 |    46   (9)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                               |                               |     1 |   526 |    43  (10)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                                    |                               |     1 |   338 |    26   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |*  4 |     HASH JOIN                                      |                               |     1 |   333 |    25   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |*  5 |      HASH JOIN                                     |                               |     1 |   324 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                                 |                               |     1 |   264 |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                                |                               |     1 |   264 |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                               |                               |     1 |   229 |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                              |                               |     1 |   215 |    17   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  10 |           NESTED LOOPS                             |                               |     1 |   192 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  11 |            NESTED LOOPS                            |                               |     1 |   153 |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  12 |             NESTED LOOPS                           |                               |     1 |   142 |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  13 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER                    |                               |     1 |    71 |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  14 |               NESTED LOOPS OUTER                   |                               |     1 |    62 |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  15 |                NESTED LOOPS OUTER                  |                               |     1 |    54 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  16 |                 NESTED LOOPS                       |                               |     1 |    42 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  17 |                  NESTED LOOPS                      |                               |     6 |   126 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  18 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | CAT_ESTATUS_ACCION            |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 19 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | PK_EST_ACC_ESTATUS_ACCION_ID  |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  20 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL                | PRAO_BLOQUES_PROGRAMADOS      |     6 |    48 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 21 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| PRAO_PROGRAMACIONES_UNIVERSOS |     1 |    21 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
    |* 22 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | IXN_PRAOPRUN_IDBLPR           |    81 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  23 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | PRAO_BRIGADAS                 |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 24 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | PK_PRAOBRIG_IDBRIG            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  25 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | PRAO_BRIGADAS_CUPOS           |     1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 26 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | PK_PRAOBRCU_IDBRCU            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  27 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | AMPO_PERSONAS                 |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 28 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | PK_AMPOPERS_IDPERS            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 29 |              TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID    | ADIO_UNIVERSOS                |     1 |    71 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
    |* 30 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | PK_ADIOUNIV_IDUNIV            |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 31 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | ADIO_ARCHIVOS_INSUMOS         |     1 |    11 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 32 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | PK_ADIOARIN_IDARIN            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  33 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | CAT_LOCALIDADES               |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 34 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                      | PK_LOCALIDADES_LOCALIDAD_ID   |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  35 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID              | CAT_MUNICIPIOS                |     1 |    23 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 36 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | PK_MUNICIPIOS_MUNICIPIO_ID    |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  37 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID               | CAT_ESTADOS                   |     1 |    14 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 38 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                        | PK_ESTADOS_ESTADO_ID          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 39 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                          | PK_PROCESOS_PROCESO_ID        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 40 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                 | CAT_PROCESOS                  |     1 |    35 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  41 |       VIEW                                         |                               |     6 |   360 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  42 |        HASH GROUP BY                               |                               |     6 |   126 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  43 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                          | PRAO_PERIODOS_PROGRAMADOS     |     6 |   126 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  44 |      VIEW                                          | index$_join$_004              |    14 |   126 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 45 |       HASH JOIN                                    |                               |       |       |            |          |       |       |
    |  46 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN                        | IXN_DIMEDEES_IDESCE           |    14 |   126 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  47 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN                        | PK_DIMEDEES_IDDEES            |    14 |   126 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 48 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                    | DIME_ESCENARIOS               |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 49 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                             | PK_DIMEESCE_IDESCE            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  50 |    VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                           |                               |     1 |   188 |    17  (18)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  51 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER                             |                               |     1 |    75 |    17  (18)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  52 |      NESTED LOOPS                                  |                               |     1 |    61 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 53 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                            | XPK_FAMILIA                   |     1 |     7 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  54 |       MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID               | INTEGRANTE                    |     1 |    54 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 55 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                            | IXN_INTEGRANTE_FAM_ES_TIT     |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  56 |      VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                         |                               |     1 |    14 |    12  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  57 |       SORT UNIQUE                                  |                               |     1 |    42 |    12  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  58 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER                          |                               |     1 |    42 |    11  (19)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  59 |         MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | DOMICILIO_FAMILIA             |     1 |    12 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 60 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                         | XPK_DOMFAM_FAMILIAID          |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  61 |          MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | DOMICILIO_FAMILIA_ANT         |     1 |    20 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 62 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                        | XPKDOMFAM_FAM_ID              |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  63 |         VIEW                                       | VM_ESTE_FAMILIAS              |     1 |    20 |     9  (23)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  64 |          NESTED LOOPS                              |                               |     1 |    14 |     9  (23)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 65 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                        | XPK_FAMILIA                   |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  66 |           VIEW                                     |                               |     1 |     2 |     6  (34)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  67 |            SORT UNIQUE                             |                               |     2 |    28 |     6  (34)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  68 |             UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE             |                               |       |       |            |          |       |       |
    |* 69 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | XPK_DOMFAM_FAMILIAID          |     1 |     7 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 70 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | XPKDOMFAM_FAM_ID              |     1 |     7 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  71 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                | CAT_MANZANAS                  |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 72 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                         | PK_MANZANAS_MANZANA_ID        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |  73 |   VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                            |                               |   318 |   636 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |* 74 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                                | IXN_DIME_IDDETALLEESCENARIO   |   557 |  1671 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

       4 - access("AAI"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO"="ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO")
       5 - access("PBP"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO"="PP"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO")
      19 - access("CEA"."ESTATUS_ACCION_ID"=1)
      21 - filter("PPU"."ID_ESTATUS_ACCION"=1)
      22 - access("PPU"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO"="PBP"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO")
      24 - access("PBP"."ID_BRIGADA"="PB"."ID_BRIGADA"(+))
      26 - access("PBP"."ID_BRIGADA_CUPO"="PBC"."ID_BRIGADA_CUPO"(+))
      28 - access("PBC"."ID_PERSONA"="AP"."ID_PERSONA"(+))
      29 - filter("AU"."CARGA_VALIDA"=1)
      30 - access("AU"."ID_UNIVERSO"="PPU"."ID_UNIVERSO")
      31 - filter("AAI"."ID_ESTATUS_ARCHIVO_UNIVERSO"=2 OR "AAI"."ID_ESTATUS_ARCHIVO_UNIVERSO"=4)
      32 - access("AAI"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO"="AU"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO")
      34 - access("AU"."ID_LOCALIDAD"="ECL"."LOCALIDAD_ID")
      36 - access("ECL"."MUNICIPIO_ID"="ECM"."MUNICIPIO_ID")
      38 - access("ECM"."ESTADO_ID"="ECE"."ESTADO_ID")
      39 - access("AAI"."ID_PROCESO"="CP"."PROCESO_ID")
      40 - filter("CP"."TIPO_PROCESO_ID"=2)
      45 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
      48 - filter("DE"."ESTATUS_ESCENARIO"=2)
      49 - access("DDE"."ID_ESCENARIO"="DE"."ID_ESCENARIO")
      53 - access("F"."FAMILIA_ID"="AU"."ID_FAMILIA_DGPL")
      55 - access("I"."ES_TITULAR"=1 AND "I"."FAMILIA_ID"="AU"."ID_FAMILIA_DGPL")
      60 - access("D"."FAMILIA_ID"=:B1)
      62 - access("FAMILIA_ID"=:B1)
      65 - access("F"."FAMILIA_ID"="F"."FAMILIA_ID")
      69 - access("DF"."FAMILIA_ID"="F"."FAMILIA_ID")
      70 - access("DFA"."FAMILIA_ID"="F"."FAMILIA_ID")
      72 - access("VMEF"."ID_MANZANA"="VMM"."MANZANA_ID"(+))
      74 - access("ID_DETALLE_ESCENARIO"="DDE"."ID_DETALLE_ESCENARIO")
```

And this is the slow query explain plan:

```
                Plan hash value: 566099118

            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Id  | Operation                                         | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                  |                               |     1 |   345 |   270   (2)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |   1 |  MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                   | INTEGRANTE                    |     1 |    37 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                                | IXN_INTEGRANTE_FAM_ES_TIT     |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |   3 |  MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                   | INTEGRANTE                    |     1 |    27 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |*  4 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                                | IXN_INTEGRANTE_FAM_ES_TIT     |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |   5 |  NESTED LOOPS                                     |                               |     2 |    84 |    12  (17)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |   6 |   NESTED LOOPS                                    |                               |     2 |    84 |    12  (17)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |   7 |    NESTED LOOPS                                   |                               |     2 |    40 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |*  8 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                             | XPK_FAMILIA                   |     1 |     7 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |   9 |     VIEW                                          |                               |     2 |    26 |     6  (34)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  10 |      SORT UNIQUE                                  |                               |     2 |    28 |     6  (34)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  11 |       UNION-ALL                                   |                               |       |       |            |          |       |       |
            |* 12 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                          | XPK_DOMFAM_FAMILIAID          |     1 |     7 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 13 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                          | XPKDOMFAM_FAM_ID              |     1 |     7 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 14 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                              | PK_MANZANAS_MANZANA_ID        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  15 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                | DOMICILIO_FAMILIA             |     1 |    12 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 16 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                            | XPK_DOMFAM_FAMILIAID          |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  17 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                | DOMICILIO_FAMILIA_ANT         |     1 |    20 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 18 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                            | XPKDOMFAM_FAM_ID              |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  19 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                     | CAT_MANZANAS                  |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  20 |  SORT AGGREGATE                                   |                               |     1 |     3 |            |          |       |       |
            |* 21 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                               | PRAO_PERIODOS_PROGRAMADOS     |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  22 |  HASH UNIQUE                                      |                               |     1 |   345 |   270   (2)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |* 23 |   HASH JOIN OUTER                                 |                               |     1 |   345 |   269   (1)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  24 |    NESTED LOOPS                                   |                               |     1 |   298 |   264   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  25 |     NESTED LOOPS                                  |                               |     1 |   298 |   264   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  26 |      NESTED LOOPS OUTER                           |                               |     1 |   284 |   263   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  27 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER                          |                               |     1 |   275 |   262   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  28 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER                         |                               |     1 |   267 |   261   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  29 |         NESTED LOOPS OUTER                        |                               |     1 |   255 |   260   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |* 30 |          FILTER                                   |                               |       |       |            |          |       |       |
            |  31 |           NESTED LOOPS OUTER                      |                               |     1 |   247 |   260   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  32 |            NESTED LOOPS                           |                               |     1 |   226 |   258   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  33 |             NESTED LOOPS                          |                               |     1 |   191 |   257   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  34 |              NESTED LOOPS                         |                               |     1 |   171 |   256   (0)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  35 |               NESTED LOOPS                        |                               |     1 |   166 |   248   (0)| 00:00:03 |       |       |
            |  36 |                NESTED LOOPS                       |                               |     1 |   132 |   247   (0)| 00:00:03 |       |       |
            |* 37 |                 HASH JOIN                         |                               |     7 |   350 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 38 |                  HASH JOIN                        |                               |     7 |   189 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  39 |                   NESTED LOOPS                    |                               |     7 |   126 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  40 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | CAT_ESTATUS_ACCION            |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 41 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_EST_ACC_ESTATUS_ACCION_ID  |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 42 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL              | DIME_ESCENARIOS               |     7 |    35 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  43 |                   VIEW                            | index$_join$_025              |    14 |   126 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 44 |                    HASH JOIN                      |                               |       |       |            |          |       |       |
            |  45 |                     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | IXN_DIMEDEES_IDESCE           |    14 |   126 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  46 |                     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | PK_DIMEDEES_IDDEES            |    14 |   126 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 47 |                  TABLE ACCESS FULL                | ADIO_ARCHIVOS_INSUMOS         |    16 |   368 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  48 |                 PARTITION RANGE ALL               |                               |     1 |    82 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |
            |* 49 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| ADIO_UNIVERSOS                |     1 |    82 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |
            |* 50 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IXN_ADIOUNIVERSOS_ARINOPERLOC |  2039K|       |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |
            |  51 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | CAT_LOCALIDADES               |     1 |    34 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 52 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | PK_LOCALIDADES_LOCALIDAD_ID   |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 53 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | DIME_DISTRIBUCIONES_METAS     |    10 |    50 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 54 |                INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | IXN_DIMEDIME_IDESIDLOIDMU     |   144 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  55 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | CAT_MUNICIPIOS                |     1 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 56 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | PK_MUNICIPIOS_MUNICIPIO_ID    |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 57 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | CAT_PROCESOS                  |     1 |    35 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 58 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | PK_PROCESOS_PROCESO_ID        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  59 |            TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID     | PRAO_PROGRAMACIONES_UNIVERSOS |     1 |    21 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
            |* 60 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                      | IXN_PRAOPRUN_IDUNIV           |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  61 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID              | PRAO_BLOQUES_PROGRAMADOS      |     1 |     8 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 62 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | PK_PRAOBLPR_IDBLPR            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  63 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID               | PRAO_BRIGADAS                 |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 64 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                        | PK_PRAOBRIG_IDBRIG            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  65 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                | PRAO_BRIGADAS_CUPOS           |     1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 66 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                         | PK_PRAOBRCU_IDBRCU            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  67 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                 | AMPO_PERSONAS                 |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 68 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                          | PK_AMPOPERS_IDPERS            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 69 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                            | PK_ESTADOS_ESTADO_ID          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  70 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                   | CAT_ESTADOS                   |     1 |    14 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  71 |    VIEW                                           |                               |     6 |   282 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  72 |     HASH GROUP BY                                 |                               |     6 |   126 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  73 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                            | PRAO_PERIODOS_PROGRAMADOS     |     6 |   126 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
            ---------------------------------------------------

               2 - access("I"."ES_TITULAR"=1 AND "I"."FAMILIA_ID"=:B1)
               4 - access("I"."ES_TITULAR"=1 AND "I"."FAMILIA_ID"=:B1)
               8 - access("F"."FAMILIA_ID"=:B1)
              12 - access("DF"."FAMILIA_ID"=:B1)
              13 - access("DFA"."FAMILIA_ID"=:B1)
              14 - access("VMM"."MANZANA_ID"=NVL( (SELECT "MANZANA_ID" FROM "VM_SIIOP"."DOMICILIO_FAMILIA" "D" WHERE "D"."FAMILIA_ID"=:B1), (SELECT 
                          "MANZANA_ID" FROM "VM_SIIOP"."DOMICILIO_FAMILIA_ANT" "DOMICILIO_FAMILIA_ANT" WHERE "FAMILIA_ID"=:B2)))
              16 - access("D"."FAMILIA_ID"=:B1)
              18 - access("FAMILIA_ID"=:B1)
              21 - filter("PRAOPERIOD1_"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO"=:B1)
              23 - access("PP"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO"(+)="PBP"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO")
              30 - filter(CASE  WHEN "PPU"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO" IS NOT NULL THEN "PPU"."ID_ESTATUS_ACCION" ELSE 0 END <>7 AND CASE  WHEN 
                          "PPU"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO" IS NOT NULL THEN "PPU"."ID_ESTATUS_ACCION" ELSE 0 END =1)
              37 - access("AAI"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO"="DDE"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO")
              38 - access("DE"."ID_ESCENARIO"="DDE"."ID_ESCENARIO")
              41 - access("ACEA"."ESTATUS_ACCION_ID"=1)
              42 - filter("DE"."ESTATUS_ESCENARIO"=2)
              44 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
              47 - filter("AAI"."ID_ESTATUS_ARCHIVO_UNIVERSO"=2 OR "AAI"."ID_ESTATUS_ARCHIVO_UNIVERSO"=4)
              49 - filter(("AU"."PROGRAMA_ID"=1 OR "AU"."PROGRAMA_ID"=2) AND "AU"."CARGA_VALIDA"=1)
              50 - access("AAI"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO"="AU"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO")
              52 - access("AU"."ID_LOCALIDAD"="ECL"."LOCALIDAD_ID")
              53 - filter("DDE"."ID_DETALLE_ESCENARIO"="DDM"."ID_DETALLE_ESCENARIO")
              54 - access("DDM"."ID_ESTADO"="AU"."ID_ESTADO")
              56 - access("AU"."ID_MUNICIPIO"="ECM"."MUNICIPIO_ID")
              57 - filter("ACP"."TIPO_PROCESO_ID"=2)
              58 - access("ACP"."PROCESO_ID"="AAI"."ID_PROCESO")
              60 - access("PPU"."ID_UNIVERSO"(+)="AU"."ID_UNIVERSO")
              62 - access("PPU"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO"="PBP"."ID_BLOQUE_PROGRAMADO"(+))
              64 - access("PB"."ID_BRIGADA"(+)="PBP"."ID_BRIGADA")
              66 - access("PBC"."ID_BRIGADA_CUPO"(+)="PBP"."ID_BRIGADA_CUPO")
              68 - access("AP"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="PBC"."ID_PERSONA")
              69 - access("AU"."ID_ESTADO"="ECE"."ESTADO_ID")
```

Comment: Post `EXPLAIN PLAN` output for both queries, or we can't help you

Comment: And I can't post the second one cuz I'm out of body space...

Comment: Should I erase the queries and post only the explain plans?

Comment: We do need both explain plans otherwise we can't compare.
We would also need to see the predicates It's usually at the bottom after the execution plan.
Every rows with a * has a predicate.

Even better if you can do this for both:
alter session set statistics_level='ALL';
<execute query without explain plan>
select * from dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'ALLSTATS LAST');

Comment: K, I put them both with their predicates. Had to erase the queries but both plans fit now.

Comment: Since you posted two different queries that do two different things and have two different plans, can you explain why they both should have the same run time?

Comment: Woops, I think I erased that along the queries. They return the same result but one query takes 280 seconds to execute while the other one only takes 7 (tops, 1 second was the quickest).
I just wanted to know what the second query had that reduced so much the execution time, so I could use it in the future.

Comment: There's a big difference between being the **"same query"** and returning the **"same result"**. Query optimisation is frequently about obtaining the same result with different queries but improving speed.

Answer (score 3):

My findings:
**Slow running query:**

```
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Id  | Operation                                         | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |  48 |                 PARTITION RANGE ALL               |                               |     1 |    82 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |
            |* 49 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| ADIO_UNIVERSOS                |     1 |    82 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |
            |* 50 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IXN_ADIOUNIVERSOS_ARINOPERLOC |  2039K|       |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |

              49 - filter(("AU"."PROGRAMA_ID"=1 OR "AU"."PROGRAMA_ID"=2) AND "AU"."CARGA_VALIDA"=1)
              50 - access("AAI"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO"="AU"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO"
```

**Fast running query:**

```
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Id  | Operation                                         | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |* 29 |              TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID    | ADIO_UNIVERSOS                |     1 |    71 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
            |* 30 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | PK_ADIOUNIV_IDUNIV            |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |

              29 - filter("AU"."CARGA_VALIDA"=1)
              30 - access("AU"."ID_UNIVERSO"="PPU"."ID_UNIVERSO")
```

I found that the table `ADIO_UNIVERSOS` is accessed by a Local Index `IXN_ADIOUNIVERSOS_ARINOPERLOC` (INDEX RANGE SCAN) which has returned 2039K rows, scans several partitions(1-17). In the fast running query the same table is accessed by Global Index `PK_ADIOUNIV_IDUNIV`(INDEX UNIQUE SCAN) has returned 1 row, which didn't run through all the partitions.

Index Range Scan obviously returns more rows than Index Unique Scan. Here, in the slow running query execution plan, Index Range Scan is influencing the Nested Loop(Cost 269).

Comment: I agree, scanning through the plan, that was the first thing I noticed as well, tune the access on that table, it should help.

Comment: What do you mean with tune the access?
I'm still new to this so I'm sorry for my lack of experience...

Comment: Analizing the database I have noticed that 'IXN_ADIOUNIVERSOS_ARINOPERLOC' is an index with 3 columns, is that affecting the performance? And why does the fast query access the primary key instead?

Comment: @Erick Travis . Your fast running query uses `PK_ADIOUNIV_IDUNIV` index  to access `ADIO_UNIVERSOS` table. In the slow running query the plan uses `IXN_ADIOUNIVERSOS_ARINOPERLOC` index to access the same table, the predicate specified has caused to scan the parition(1-17). So yeah problem may exists around that index. Tune the access mean analyze the access methods(index range scan, unique scan, full scan etc). You can do that by changing the predicate used.

Comment: What if I can't modify or add any indexes? Is there some thing I can do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the bad query only:
The following section is where your performance issues start:

```
|  36 |                NESTED LOOPS                       |                               |     1 |   132 |   247   (0)| 00:00:03 |       |       |
            |* 37 |                 HASH JOIN                         |                               |     7 |   350 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 38 |                  HASH JOIN                        |                               |     7 |   189 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  39 |                   NESTED LOOPS                    |                               |     7 |   126 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  40 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | CAT_ESTATUS_ACCION            |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 41 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_EST_ACC_ESTATUS_ACCION_ID  |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 42 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL              | DIME_ESCENARIOS               |     7 |    35 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  43 |                   VIEW                            | index$_join$_025              |    14 |   126 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 44 |                    HASH JOIN                      |                               |       |       |            |          |       |       |
            |  45 |                     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | IXN_DIMEDEES_IDESCE           |    14 |   126 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  46 |                     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | PK_DIMEDEES_IDDEES            |    14 |   126 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 47 |                  TABLE ACCESS FULL                | ADIO_ARCHIVOS_INSUMOS         |    16 |   368 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  48 |                 PARTITION RANGE ALL               |                               |     1 |    82 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |
            |* 49 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| ADIO_UNIVERSOS                |     1 |    82 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |
            |* 50 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IXN_ADIOUNIVERSOS_ARINOPERLOC |  2039K|       |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    17 |
```

The cost of that nested loop is almost all the cost of your query.
Looking into that, Row 50 is accessing an index IXN_ADIOUNIVERSOS_ARINOPERLOC and planning to pull 2 million rows using the following predicate:

```
50 - access("AAI"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO"="AU"."ID_ARCHIVO_INSUMO")
```

However, still based on estimates, it will filter all the rows out and keep only 1 (row 49)

```
49 - filter(("AU"."PROGRAMA_ID"=1 OR "AU"."PROGRAMA_ID"=2) AND "AU"."CARGA_VALIDA"=1)
```

it's very inefficient to grab so much rows just to throw out all of them minus 1.
If you didn't find a way to rewrite that query yet, I would have told you to add the columns from predicate 49 in an index with column from predicate 50.

Also running the query and gather runtime statistics would tell us if the estimates match the actual run (I gave you instructions in comments).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand how to do what you said, tried to run it in sqldeveloper replacing the sentence between brackets with my queries but it returned an error.
I probably got something wrong, sorry.